# white molds to top of 3 days old pear wine bucket,

Tags: fermenter, plastic, fruit-wine

I see some white molds on top of my plastic wine  fermenter bucket just in first 3 days old pear wine , my question is that if it is dangerous or not? if not then how can i get rid of those molds?

Comment: would you be able to add a photo?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a number of beers and meads that after a week, fermenting in fridge, have had the bucket covered in mold. I don't know which kind of bucket you use, I use [these](http://www.recozil.com.br/produtos/bombonas/bombona-30-litros-tr/).
Since they are very well sealed, every time I had this "problem", I washed the exterior with a washing brush and sprayed a sanitizer all over the exterior. Until now I had no contaminated secondary fermentation.
But be twice as diligent as when sanitizing it for fermentation. Oh, and when removing the lid, do it slowly, there might be some mold hiding in the joint.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to get rid of said mould,is to pour the stuff down the drain, based on my experience. Did you use STARSAN?